# Http Client sents request twice

Tags: c#, httplistener

I'm using an http client and an http server(listener)
In some cases when i'm having big delay-traffic in my network, http client sends request but it nevers takes a response from http listener.As a result i'm trying to resend my request to server. But, server already has took previous one request and re-runs the new one. In this case, server runs my request twice.

## httplistener

```
 HttpListener listener;
    Thread t;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadMethod));
        t.IsBackground = true;
        listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.0.214:8282/");
        listener.Start();
        t.Start();
       // label1.Text = "Opened";
    }
    void MyThreadMethod()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    public void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {

        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        string methodName = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Url);

        //Here is my code

        string Response = "OK";
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        string responseString = Convert.ToString(Response);
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        output.Close();


    }
```

## And here is my httpClient

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent("my Data", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = client.PostAsync("http://192.168.0.214:8282/", content).Result;
```

How can i prevent, when i'm having big delay_ms in my network, http listener running twice my requests?

Comment: The network can never be assumed to be *reliable* and POST is not idempotent so not *safe* to automatically resend. Given these two things, what help are you actually looking for here?

Comment: What help can you give me to solve my problem? Is it better to use Get instead Post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common issue for distributed applications. You make a request, someone gets it, sometimes complete the request sometimes can not. Furthermore, sometimes you get the response and sometimes not. To deal with such situations, the rule of thumb is "your commands/requests should be **idempotent**". I mean, even if you send a request/command several times to a service, the result should not change and the command should only be executed only once. Accomplishing this sometimes can be very complicated but for simple scenarios  you can simply accomplish this by adding a command id to your requests and a command log to your server. When server receives the request, it first checks whether this command already executed. If it was executed before, it returns the same success response, otherwise runs the command.

Comment: Nice approach. I understand exactly what you mean... But i'm wondering is there any better method for avoiding this? Example when i used the same method with asp net, i didn't have same issues. Almost none of them. Why this is happened?

Comment: IIS is a full, more complicated and more reliable environment for building and hosting web applications. It has well designed mechanisms for handling and managing requests and responses. It has very good request queue and worker architecture. But you use simple web request/listener classes, they are really simple. You may consider develop a web API and hosting it in IIS.

Comment: Is there posiibility to have the same problem using a web api?

Comment: When you host your web API in IIS, it will benefit from IIS's request pooling and parallel execution features. When high work and network loads the possibility always exists, but ISS will make things a bit better. You should never rely on the network and remote server availability and take necessary precautions.

Comment: Is there any good tutorial for giving me an example? How http client will create a unique id? and how server will store it ?  And what if two http clients will send the same ID? How i will prevent that? Or even better if there is a way to check from server that client has took my response

Comment: You can use Guid.NewGuid() method to generate unique ids on the same and different machines. I use it for years and it never failed. For sample, I do not think that you need a sample code. Since a simple table with the request's id and its result is enough. If your operation has many steps, you may need to hold at which state it is. So you can rollback the executed steps or continue executing the remaining steps later. Do not think complex, improve your code and algorithm when you need.

Comment: Do you remove this ID's after a specific time?

Comment: It depends, if there is no or low possibility of "request replay" attack for your system, you can possibly delete old records periodically (e.g 24 hours later).